# Как в Vim удалить строку, подходящую под заданный шаблон?

Tags: vim

Как можно в виме удалить строку, соответствующую шаблону?

`:%s/pattern//g` просто заменит на пустую строку.
А как сделать именно удаление, не оставляя пустой строки?

<sup>По мотивам «[vim: найти и удалить строку](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/2551982)»</sup>

Comment: а модификатор `g` здесь зачем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь командой `:global`.

```
:g/pattern/d
```